# Install SampleManager on Windows server 2016 with Microsoft SQL Server 2016 sp2 using one instance in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-compute-engine

I want the basic steps to carry out the above task in GCP, need to do this ASAP for a client. I have a Gsuite account, what should i do next, eg. do i need to register a domain, create IAM users, create a project etc

Comment: Can you provide more information about your goal ? Please update your question with your desired setup. Generarily you have to start from [creating a Windows VM Instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/quickstart-windows#create_a_windows_server_vm_instance) and connecting via RDP - besides that you can install everything just like on any other machine.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to [create a Windows Server 2016 VM](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/quickstart-windows#create_a_windows_server_vm_instance).

Next set up remote desktop;

> In the Google Cloud Console, go to the VM instances page.
>
> - Go to VM instances
> - Under the Name column, click the name of your virtual machine instance.
> - Under the Remote access section, click Set Windows password.
> - Specify a username, then click Set to generate a new password for this Windows Server instance. Save the username and password so you can log into the instance.

Here's more info about [setting up RDP for Windows instances](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/chrome-desktop-remote-windows-compute-engine).

To [connect](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-windows#windows_gui) to such instance you need either Chrome RDP extension which is available for most OS'es including ChromeOS.

Next install Microsoft SQL database engine - all the [instructions are provided here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).

Then you can install SampleManager the same way using graphical interface.

Comment: Hello @Dalu and welcome to StackOverflow! Please remember to [react to answers for your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). 
That way we know if the answers were helpful and other community members could also benefit from them. Try to [accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) that is the final solution for your issue, upvote answers that are helpful and comment on those which could be improved or require additional attention. Enjoy your stay!